# Magento2 on list page click page 2 or 3 at the bottom of the page. Go about 8 products down. No product image is coming only the loading image

Tags: magento2

[image]

On list page magento2 click page 2 or 3 at the bottom of the page. Go about 8 products down. No product image is coming only the loading image. The issue is random, if you click CTRL-F5 sometimes the products images comes.

Comment: Are you using any third party extension for pagination ?

Comment: not using any third party extension for pagination but on image we are using lazyload script

Comment: I can see, you are using Aheadworks_Layerednav extension and that's responsible for AJAX pagination, right ? I have one solution for this.

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: Aheadworks_Layerednav extension is using for showing filters search

Comment: open this file "Aheadworks_Layerednav/js/product-list/pager.js", and add 'alert("TEST");' after 'updater.updateAndScrollUpToTop(updateUrl, requestBridge.getResult());' line. And let me know if alert shows after pagination AJAX completes.

Comment: i am doing let you know

Comment: not showing me any alert

Comment: iam trying on localhost ... i am doing deploy now

Comment: not showing alert

Comment: i have edit in same file that you tell me above

Comment: iam working on localhost so link will not opened on your pc

Comment: m2.roykon.dk/dk this is live site link i can't update here thats why i checked in localhost

Comment: Then it's hard to help, just try to get an alert after pagination AJAX completes. Search in all Aheadworks_Layerednav js files.